# kotlin surfaceview ontouchlistener

Tags: android, kotlin, ontouchlistener

I am working on android surface view with touch events.

Below is the code I wrote for surface view to handle touch events.

[image: Problem screenshot]

As shown in the image, I logged when the listener is called.

Then in when clause I handled ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_MOVE events.

However, when I touch the view, not only the when clause can't catch the event

but OnTouchListener is even not called too.

I also don't understand why `true`s in when clause are not used.

I wrote those expressions to tell OnTouchListener to return true.

Can anyone help me?

+) I figured out that my surfaceview doens't call `onClick()` too.

```
particleSurfaceView.setOnClickListener{ Log.d("sv", "click") }
```

never logs

Answer (score 0):

Try making the touch listener always return true. If you ever return false, you stop getting notifications for that whole gesture / touch.

Comment: It didn't work. It never gets touch event, not event the very first time

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was Android Studio problem..

Touch event works but only the logging didn't work.

I have no idea why but after relaunching the Android Studio, it works.